# Content Types created in Visual Studio don't appear in Document Information Panel

Tags: document-info-panel

Hallo I'm proceeding this way:

- create some site columns and content types using them, in VS2013
- reference some docx/dotx
- attach them to the Content Type using elements.xml
- create a Library Template
- attach the content types to the list
- deploy to SP2013 (Foundation)
- create a new document
- the document often opens up in Word 2013 with empty Document Information Panel

If I open it manually, it shows only "Title".

The odd fact is that in some cases the DIP shows correctly: I'm trying to understand which is the lucky combination.

If I create the Content Type and the Library by hand in SP it works.

Answer (score 0):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

I found a possible explaination [at this link](http://platinumdogs.me/2010/01/15/provision-a-content-type-with-a-document-template-using-a-feature-part-1/), both the two parts of the article are meaningful.
And as stated in the post, [this post](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2009/10/30/problem-solved-amnesia-problem-multiple-content-types-on-libraries/) may give further help about the issue.

BTW is not related to DIP nor to Office versione nor to document format (I tried both docx and dotx). It is indeed related to how the content type document template is uploaded/specified, and thus while doing it in a declarative way a more detailed XML than just "DocumentTemplate TargetName" is needed:

```
<ContentType ID="0x0101002880177DFDC248c38C745E1D664A5FC5"
                 Name="Doc Sample"
                 Description="Test CT with DT"
                 Group="_Custom">
    <FieldRefs />
    <DocumentTemplate TargetName="doc1.dotx"/>
</ContentType>
<Module Name="PopulateDocTemplates"
          Url="_cts/Doc Sample"
          RootWebOnly="TRUE"
          Path="templates"
          SetupPath="Features\MyTestContentTypes\templates">
    <File Url="doc1.dotx" />
</Module>
```